# Web Application with Sample "guest" data

Tags: java, mysql

we are currently working on a new web application using Java and MySql. We would like to implement a "guest" login feature. The idea is simple: anyone can login as a guest user and get access to a small pre-defined dataset which they can then interact with as if they were fully paid up clients.

This feature should have these attributes:

- Allow multiple concurrent guest logins without cross-talk
- When the guest session closes any changes will be lost
- The guest login should not be too slow

Here are a few ideas that we have come up with, although each has it Pros and Cons:

**1. Treat them as any other client and store them in the MySql database.**

PROS

- Easier to implement
- No sublte differences can occur

CONS

- Polutes the live database with sample data
- Problem of "initial state" not solved
- Clean-up is not automatic

**2. Use an In-memory temporary database solution**

PROS

- No cross-talk
- Initial state can be loaded as an image?
- Clean up is trivial

CONS

- The In-memory database and MySql might not support the same features or differently
- There may be scaling issues

My question is: what would be the best way to achieve this? Is there a best-practive for this type of thing?

Thanks in advance,

Steve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'd go with option 3 ... using a separate schema or database with the same structure/infrastructure as your live database.

PROS

- Easier to implement
- No sublte differences can occur
- Doesn't polute the live database with
  sample data
- The MySql will
  support the same features
- There won't be scaling issues

CONS/things you'll still need to solve:

- Initial state - and i'd suggest a
  simple script/routine to pre-populate
  as needed
- Clean-up is not automatic - and again
  a simple script/routine at end of
  session

Comment: After thinking about, it makes sense to have a seperate guest instance. It turns the initial state/clean-up issues into minor plumbing issues. For example, I could imagine having a guest DB backup file with X guest datasets ready for use. In this case, we just have to perform a restore at some regular interval.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you have a guest based system providing sample data, you don't point to the live database for these users - you point them to a special guest version. There are many reasons for this, but the main one is that you can roll the database back to a checkpoint of the sample data without affecting the live users.